# "Brand® product" or "Brand product" in title?

Tags: seo, keywords, title, branding, trademark

We have always used `Brand® product` in the `title` element (because this is what it is). People of course search for `Brand product` and not `Brand® product`.

I am in doubt. We are being advised to remove the registered icon and use `Brand product` in the `title`. But I am not certain about this: I would imagine that Google knows what it is doing and recognizes this icon.

**Question:** Would one use `Brand® product` or `Brand product` when trying to rank for `Brand product`?

#### References

- http://forums.seochat.com/seo-help-general-chat-16/what-impact-can-using-registered-trademark-symbol-title-tag-have-why-467462.html
- http://www.ecreativeworks.com/blog/2007/04/18/the-title-tag-an-rare-seo-question-answered/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google handles special chars, and it seems they don't affect rankings:

```
https://www.google.es/search?q=Google%C2%AE&oq=Google%C2%AE
https://www.google.es/search?q=Google*&oq=Google*
https://www.google.es/search?q=Google*%2F&oq=Google*%2F
```

; but as Matt said, you should avoid to make thinks harder for robots, google's or any others:

[How does Google handle special characters? by Matt Cutts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suTDT6-Q8NE)

Comment: I believe that in 2020 this topic is a bit more updated. I was having the same thoughts but I just found that searching in google for BVOP™, BVOP and BVOP® gives me slightly different results every time. it seems that today fully ignoring special characters by Google is not exactly the real case.

Comment: @AntonRadev, more than "slightly different".  Using quotation marks, "BVOP" returns 499,000 results, "BVOP®" 483,000, and "BVOP™" only 1,290, and without quotation marks "BVOP" returns 613,000 results.  I haven't actually compared, but I suspect the unquoted "BVOP" results will include all the others.  If that's true, since almost everyone will search without the quotation marks and special characters, the presence of these characters in the title wouldn't affect the searches.

Comment: Just to enfatize that I wrote rankings, not serps (as the question pointed). I'm on @RayButterworth hypotesis that "open" search will probably include more singular searchs.